# Static IP - Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 - cannot ping each other,

Tags: networking

I have a Windows 10 computer and a Ubuntu 20.04 computer
the WIFI is really slow for transferring files in between the computers.  (2MB/sec)

So I connected a standard cable in between the two systems and set up static ip addresses.  The ports are gigabit so should not need a crossover cable.

They can't ping each other.  But can ping themselves.

192.168.2.1 - Ubuntu 20.04 - gigabit

192.168.2.2 - Win10 - gigabit

10.0.0.164 - Ubuntu 20.04 - WIFI

10.0.0.253 - Win10 - WIFI

```
tufa@HP-xw4600-Workstation:/$ ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms

--- 192.168.2.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2030ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.048/0.058/0.065/0.007 ms
```

```
tufa@HP-xw4600-Workstation:/$ ping 192.168.2.2
PING 192.168.2.2 (192.168.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.2.2 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4104ms
```

```
tufa@HP-xw4600-Workstation:/$ ping 10.0.0.253
PING 10.0.0.253 (10.0.0.253) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.253: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=20.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.253: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=8.64 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.253: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=7.61 ms

--- 10.0.0.253 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.605/12.209/20.385/5.796 ms
```

```
tufa@HP-xw4600-Workstation:/$ sudo lshw -C network
  

*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5755 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.0
       logical name: enp63s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:21:5a:6a:85:0c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=5.15.0-100-generic duplex=full firmware=5755-v3.29 ip=192.168.2.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:28 memory:e3000000-e300ffff
  

*-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:2
       logical name: wlx00e0202f59d2
       serial: 00:e0:20:2f:59:d2
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188fu driverversion=5.15.0-100-generic ip=10.0.0.164 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11gn
```

It shows "port=twisted pair" and "link=yes". Link shows connected on win10.

Both have subnetmask 255.255.255.0 (/24)

They can ping each other on WIFI and I can transfer files via samba.

Comment: You are probably missing a route ... You'll need to configure a route for packets to go through ... Like on Ubuntu use `ip route add Windows_IP via Ubuntu_IP dev device_name` ... and on Windows configure it from the interface properties GUI (or however it's configured) reversing IPs.

Comment: .. Another easy way is to rely on the "link-local address" ... That is set both machines to acquire IPs via DHCP on the interfaces and simply connect the cable and wait for both interfaces to be assigned an IP in the `169.254.x.x` range and use those IPs and those should work out of the box allowing packets between the two machines IIRC.

Comment: HP-xw4600-Workstation is my Ubuntu system.
Setting both to DHCP they got IPs of 169.254.x.x.  I can now transfer files at 100MB/sec!
I attempted to put gateways of 192.168.2.1 on my windows 10 system and 192.168.2.2 on my Ubuntu system but that didn't seem to work.
With the 169.254.x.x IPs they don't have a gateway.  I connected my Win10 Laptop to my Win10 Desktop and set static IPs again but that didn't work either.  Tomorrow I'm going to boot off a Ubuntu 20.04 USB stick and set static again and maybe see if it is Windows which is the issue.

Comment: Connecting machines to each other via two interfaces simultaneously (Ethernet and WiFi) can cause problems. Try to disable WiFi on each machine and have them connected only via cable, then try again.

Comment: Disconnecting the wifi made it work.  But then I didn't have internet.
So I followed this guide to bridge my wireless router and disabled both wifi adapters. https://community.tp-link.com/us/home/forum/topic/175380%20